# make command line with arguments

Tags: vb.net, command

I have textbox1.text and it has the user input text.

There are the main command and such. One of them is ip
If the user types `ip local` I want it to display the local ip, which I already have the code for

Another example would be `ping google.com 1000` It would ping google for 1000MS, again I already have the code for it, but how would I get the 1000 or what if it wasn't there? it would just ping it once. I don't want an error to pop up.

code:

```
Dim text As String = TextBox1.Text
server.Start()
If text.StartsWith("ip") And text.EndsWith(" local") Then
    response = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList(0).ToString()
end if
```

Comment: `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() As String()` will parse the command line into a string array...what are you using now?

Comment: Show us some code. What did you try?

Comment: What do you mean using now?

Comment: I updated it to show the code I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe you want something like this instead:

```
Dim array() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim cmd as String = array(0).ToUpper()

If cmd = "IP" Then
   IpConfig  array 
Else If cmd = "PING" Then
   Ping array
End If
```

Next add each command as a Sub or Function or whatever....

```
Public Sub IpConfig( byVal array() as String)
   ' your code

End Sub

More commands.....
```

Comment: That works awesome but if the user types IP local how would I be able to get the local, or if they type IP local 2000 how can I get the 2000

Comment: all those values will be in the array.  for example, in the IPConfig sub you should get the count of the array.  If the count is 2 then they must have provided  "host port" so array(1) is the host and array(2) is the port.    Each Sub will have to get a count and handle each operation independently.

Comment: Works amazing! Thank you so much :)